# How to implement bindings of multiple properties to all listen to each other?

Tags: java, javafx

I have two `Circle` nodes that are dragable, and I want to connect them with a `Line` that connects the nodes (not from their center, but from their perimeter). But as one `Circle` changes location as it is getting dragged, the `Line`'s `startX` and `startY` values change so the `Line` becomes the shortest line between the two `Circle`s, collinear with the line connecting their radii.

My problem is that it seems overly verbose to have the `Line`'s `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, and `endY` each individually listen to or bind to both `Circle`s' `centerXProperty` and `centerYProperty` (or rather, bind to a calculation with those properties' values), as that would result in 16 total bindings/listeners.

I was wondering if there exists an easier or more convenient way to accomplish this. I was considering creating a `SimpleDoubleProperty` that would be the slope of the `Line` object (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1), binding to the two `centerXProperty`s and `centerYProperty`s, and have `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, and `endY` each listen to that property, but I'm also not sure how to have a single property bind to the resultant calculation of those four properties.

Here is how I'm currently constructing my `Line`. I was experimenting for the `startXProperty` and `startYProperty` binding and realized it properly updated the `Line` but ONLY when the source Circle `source` was moved, which prompted me to ask this question. The `endXProperty` and `endYProperty` still both have the `Line` anchored at the target Circle's center. I can provide my entire code if needed although I think this should suffice for what I'm trying to accomplish.

```java
public GraphEdge(GraphNode source, GraphNode target) {
    this.source = source;
    this.target = target;
    this.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    this.startXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        slope = (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY())/(target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX());
        return source.getCenterX() + Math.cos(Math.atan(slope)) * source.getRadius();
        }, source.boundsInParentProperty()));
    this.startYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        slope = (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY())/(target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX());
        return source.getCenterY() + Math.sin(Math.atan(slope)) * source.getRadius();
    }, source.boundsInParentProperty()));
    this.endXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        Bounds b = target.getBoundsInParent();
        return b.getMinX() + b.getWidth() / 2;
    }, target.boundsInParentProperty()));
    this.endYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        Bounds b = target.getBoundsInParent();
        return b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2;
    }, target.boundsInParentProperty()));
}
```

Comment: A quick question: are your Circles have only border or do they also have fill color?

Comment: Just in case: if the circles have some some background color or fill, then you don't need to worry about the points on circles. Just connect the line between the centers and ensure the line is behind the two circles :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`createDoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-) accepts a list of dependencies. You should list all of the properties each line property depends on.

```
this.startXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> {
        double slope = (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY())/(target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX());
        return source.getCenterX() + Math.cos(Math.atan(slope)) * source.getRadius();
    },
    source.centerXProperty(),
    source.centerYProperty(),
    target.centerXProperty(),
    target.centerYProperty(),
    source.radiusProperty(),
));
```

Repeat for the three other line properties.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @John Kugelman answer.

I gave a quick try and looks like your actual formula (using sin/tan) is not working for me as expected.
So I gave a rethink about the logic and came up with the below solution. This solution is based on the concept of "Given line AB, find a point C on line which is at a distance d". Here A and B are the centers of the circles.

So the idea is :

- We build a DoubleBinding to get the length(l) of the line between centers of circles.
- Then we calculate the points which are at a distance of radius 'r' and 'l-r'. The points sits on the edges of the two circles.
- Lastly, we build a line by binding with the new points.

Please find the below code:

```
class GraphEdge extends Line {
    public GraphEdge(GraphNode source, GraphNode target) {
        DoubleBinding lineLength = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double xDiffSqu = (target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX()) * (target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX());
            double yDiffSqu = (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY()) * (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY());
            return Math.sqrt(xDiffSqu + yDiffSqu);
        }, source.centerXProperty(), source.centerYProperty(), target.centerXProperty(), target.centerYProperty());

        DoubleBinding sTx = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, false, Circle::getCenterX);
        DoubleBinding sTy = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, false, Circle::getCenterY);
        DoubleBinding eTx = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, true, Circle::getCenterX);
        DoubleBinding eTy = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, true, Circle::getCenterY);

        setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        setStrokeWidth(2);
        startXProperty().bind(sTx);
        startYProperty().bind(sTy);
        endXProperty().bind(eTx);
        endYProperty().bind(eTy);
    }

    private DoubleBinding pointBinding(Circle startDot, Circle endDot, DoubleBinding lineLength, boolean isFarEnd, Function<Circle, Double> refPoint) {
        return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double dt = isFarEnd ? lineLength.get() - endDot.getRadius() : startDot.getRadius();
            double t = dt / lineLength.get();
            double startPoint = refPoint.apply(startDot);
            double endPoint = refPoint.apply(endDot);
            double dy = ((1 - t) * startPoint) + (t * endPoint);
            return dy;
        }, lineLength);
    }
}
```

Below is the complete working demo:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class DoubleBindingsDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;");
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

        GraphNode greenNode = new GraphNode("green");
        GraphNode redNode = new GraphNode("red");
        GraphEdge edge = new GraphEdge(greenNode, redNode);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(greenNode, redNode, edge);
    }

    class GraphNode extends Circle {
        double sceneX, sceneY, centerX, centerY;

        public GraphNode(String color) {
            double radius = 30;
            setRadius(radius);
            setStyle("-fx-fill:" + color + ";-fx-stroke-width:2px;-fx-stroke:black;-fx-opacity:.5");
            setCenterX(radius);
            setCenterY(radius);
            setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                sceneX = e.getSceneX();
                sceneY = e.getSceneY();
                centerX = getCenterX();
                centerY = getCenterY();
            });

            EventHandler<MouseEvent> dotOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = e -> {
                // Offset of drag
                double offsetX = e.getSceneX() - sceneX;
                double offsetY = e.getSceneY() - sceneY;

                // Taking parent bounds
                Bounds parentBounds = getParent().getLayoutBounds();
                double dotRadius = getRadius();
                double maxCx = parentBounds.getWidth() - dotRadius;
                double maxCy = parentBounds.getHeight() - dotRadius;

                double cxOffset = centerX + offsetX;
                double cyOffset = centerY + offsetY;
                if (cxOffset < dotRadius) {
                    setCenterX(dotRadius);
                } else if (cxOffset < maxCx) {
                    setCenterX(cxOffset);
                } else {
                    setCenterX(maxCx);
                }

                if (cyOffset < dotRadius) {
                    setCenterY(dotRadius);
                } else if (cyOffset < maxCy) {
                    setCenterY(cyOffset);
                } else {
                    setCenterY(maxCy);
                }
            };
            setOnMouseDragged(dotOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        }
    }

    class GraphEdge extends Line {
        public GraphEdge(GraphNode source, GraphNode target) {
            DoubleBinding lineLength = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
                double xDiffSqu = (target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX()) * (target.getCenterX() - source.getCenterX());
                double yDiffSqu = (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY()) * (target.getCenterY() - source.getCenterY());
                return Math.sqrt(xDiffSqu + yDiffSqu);
            }, source.centerXProperty(), source.centerYProperty(), target.centerXProperty(), target.centerYProperty());

            DoubleBinding sTx = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, false, Circle::getCenterX);
            DoubleBinding sTy = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, false, Circle::getCenterY);
            DoubleBinding eTx = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, true, Circle::getCenterX);
            DoubleBinding eTy = pointBinding(source, target, lineLength, true, Circle::getCenterY);

            setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            setStrokeWidth(2);
            startXProperty().bind(sTx);
            startYProperty().bind(sTy);
            endXProperty().bind(eTx);
            endYProperty().bind(eTy);
        }

        private DoubleBinding pointBinding(Circle startDot, Circle endDot, DoubleBinding lineLength, boolean isFarEnd, Function<Circle, Double> refPoint) {
            return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
                double dt = isFarEnd ? lineLength.get() - endDot.getRadius() : startDot.getRadius();
                double t = dt / lineLength.get();
                double startPoint = refPoint.apply(startDot);
                double endPoint = refPoint.apply(endDot);
                double dy = ((1 - t) * startPoint) + (t * endPoint);
                return dy;
            }, lineLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, my formula seemed to work using the concept of the two centers and finding the slope, then using arctan to find the angle, and finally using the angle to find the other two sides. I didn't do the target circle yet but I will keep this in mind!

Comment: Using your formula, i get the perfect line only when the two circles are in 45deg slope. For all the positions, the line points sits elsewhere.. but not on the circle boundary.

Comment: Strange. I only had the issue where the line would start or end elsewhere depending on the relative x-coordinates of the circles. I remedied this by having a variable `offset` = `Math.sin(Math.atan(slope))*target.getRadius()` (using sin or cosine, target or source, depending on the property) and either adding or subtracting that offset from the center coordinate depending on the circles' relative x-coordinates.